# Android Studio constraint layout change absolute

Tags: java, android, layout, android-constraintlayout

i need to edit absolute values of ImageView:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
```

to

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp"
```

but in java if I just do

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)(img.getLayoutParams());
params1.editorAbsoluteY = 50;
img.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your value from DP to pixels:

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

before setting the params1.editorAbsoluteY.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutParams always deal with pixel values.

So you'll need to convert your DP to PX values before setting the values on the LayoutParams. There are many examples of this, a quick google should do it.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to give more information than simply saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: the "It doesn't work" means it doesn't do the change the value.